# Definite integral, $\frac 1{\ln(x)}$

Tags: definite-integrals

What is $$\int_0^{\pi^{2}}\frac 1{\ln(x)}dx$$

I tried using complex residues and some identities, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like this integral is not converging: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E%28pi%5E2%29+1%2Fln%28x%29dx

Comment: you will need special functions like the Exponential Integral to caluclate this integral

Comment: First , $x\ne1$

Comment: This is the [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) function, evaluated at $\pi^2$.

Comment: Its Cauchy principal value equals ${\it Ei} \left( 2\,\ln  \left( \pi  \right)  \right) $, where ${\it Ei}$ is the exponential integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of integral is called a *logarithmic integral function* $\mathrm{li}(x)$. A logarithmic integral function is used in physics and number theory.

In the case of having $0$ and $\pi^2$ as your bounds, the function would be $\mathrm{li}(\pi^2) - \mathrm{li}(0)$ which simplifies to $\mathrm{li}(\pi^2)$. Calculating it would be tedious and you would definitely not need to learn the long equation from the integral table, so you may just refer to it as $\mathrm{li}(\pi^2)$ instead of figuring out the actual answer. It's acceptable in mathematics.

**EDIT:** using a [logarithmic integral calculator](http://www.had2know.com/academics/logarithmic-integral-calculator.html) evaluated at an approximation of $\pi^2$, the solution to this integral is approximately $6.019$

**EDIT 2:** incase you wanted to see the equation, because it is equal to the exponential integral $\mathrm{Ei}(\ln x)$, your integral would be

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\ln \pi^2}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm{dt}
\end{equation}

However, because when $t$ is $0$, the $\mathrm{Ei}$ function is undefined at $0$, you must make it the sum of two integrals approaching 0.

\begin{equation}
\underset{h \to 0}{\lim} \int_{-\ln \pi^2}^{-h}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm{dt} + \int_{h}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm{dt}
\end{equation}

Which in the end equals approximately $6.019$

Answer (score 9):

**Divergent Integral**

Using the substitution $x=e^{-t}$, we get
$$
\int_0^{\pi^2}\frac1{\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
=-\int_{-2\log(\pi)}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}t\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}
$$
This is not convergent near $t=0$, that is, near $x=1$.

However, we can compute the [Cauchy Principal Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

---

**Principal Value**

First, we look at an interval symmetric about $t=0$ and use the odd part of $e^{-t}$.
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{PV}\int_{-2\log(\pi)}^{2\log(\pi)}\frac{e^{-t}}t\,\mathrm{d}t
&=-\int_{-2\log(\pi)}^{2\log(\pi)}\frac{\sinh(t)}t\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
&=-\int_{-2\log(\pi)}^{2\log(\pi)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}\\[6pt]
&=-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2\log(\pi))^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)(2k+1)!}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Power Series**

Next, for any $x$, we can compute
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{2\log(\pi)}^x\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\int_{2\log(\pi)}^x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kt^{k-1}}{k!}\,\mathrm{d}t\\[6pt]
&=\log\left(\frac{x}{2\log(\pi)}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^k}{k\,k!}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-2\log(\pi))^k}{k\,k!}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
We handle the rest with an asymptotic expansion.

---

**Asymptotic Expansion**

Let
$$
f(x)=xe^x\int_x^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{4}
$$
then
$$
f'(x)=\left(1+\frac1x\right)f(x)-1\tag{5}
$$
Using $(5)$ we can compute the asymptotic expansion
$$
f(x)=1-\frac{1!}x+\frac{2!}{x^2}-\frac{3!}{x^3}+\frac{4!}{x^4}-\frac{5!}{x^5}+\dots\tag{6}
$$
Therefore, asymptotically,
$$
\int_x^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\sim\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\left(1-\frac{1!}x+\frac{2!}{x^2}-\frac{3!}{x^3}+\frac{4!}{x^4}-\frac{5!}{x^5}+\dots\right)\tag{7}
$$

---

**Synthesis**

We will compute the integral to $20$ places using $(2)$ with $16$ terms, $(3)$ with $x=50$ and $180$ terms, and $(7)$ says the rest is insignificant.
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{PV}\int_{-2\log(\pi)}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}t\,\mathrm{d}t
&=-6.14177296941047095756+0.03296521755189987579\\
&=-6.10880775185857108177
\end{align}
$$
Therefore
$$
\mathrm{PV}\int_0^{\pi^2}\frac1{\log(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t=6.10880775185857108177
$$